# R code to generate difference in appointment date and current visit date

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I'm doing a project and need to determine the interruption in treatment based on missed patient appointment dates. I have two dates "Date of Visit" and "Next Appointment date, recorded for a patient on different visit days. As in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JANKT.png) I want help with an R code to generate the duration from the last appointment date (red) to the current visit date (blue) for each visit and patient.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Ekerette, please share the data or a sample of the data as r code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

1. if your date is character form then use line1 to transform to date format with `dmy` function from `lubridate` (you can omit this line if not needed)
2. group by `ID`
3. Use `as.numeric` to get numbers within substraction of `dateVisit` and `lag()` of `NextAppointment`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(DateVisit, NextAppointment), dmy)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Duration = as.numeric(DateVisit - lag(NextAppointment)))
```

```
      ID Visitnum DateVisit  NextAppointment Duration
   <int>    <int> <date>     <date>             <dbl>
 1     1        1 2020-03-16 2020-04-11            NA
 2     1        2 2020-04-09 2020-07-02            -2
 3     1        3 2020-06-11 2020-09-24           -21
 4     1        4 2020-12-20 2021-03-15            87
 5     1        5 2021-03-23 2021-06-23             8
 6     1        6 2021-06-20 2021-12-15            -3
 7     1        7 2022-02-01 2022-07-29            48
 8     1        8 2022-07-29 2023-01-25             0
 9     2        1 2020-04-09 2020-07-02            NA
10     2        2 2020-06-11 2020-09-24           -21
11     2        3 2020-12-12 2021-03-06            79
12     2        4 2020-03-07 2020-04-04          -364
13     2        5 2021-03-22 2021-06-21           352
14     2        6 2021-06-20 2021-12-15            -1
15     2        7 2021-12-12 2022-06-12            -3
16     2        8 2022-06-12 2022-12-08             0
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Visitnum = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), DateVisit = c("16-Mar-2020", 
"09-Apr-2020", "11-Jun-2020", "20-Dec-2020", "23-Mar-2021", "20-Jun-2021", 
"01-Feb-2022", "29-Jul-2022", "09-Apr-2020", "11-Jun-2020", "12-Dec-2020", 
"07-Mar-2020", "22-Mar-2021", "20-Jun-2021", "12-Dec-2021", "12-Jun-2022"
), NextAppointment = c("11-Apr-2020", "02-Jul-2020", "24-Sep-2020", 
"15-Mar-2021", "23-Jun-2021", "15-Dec-2021", "29-Jul-2022", "25-Jan-2023", 
"02-Jul-2020", "24-Sep-2020", "06-Mar-2021", "04-Apr-2020", "21-Jun-2021", 
"15-Dec-2021", "12-Jun-2022", "08-Dec-2022")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tarjae for the very wonderful support. I really appreciate it.